# How can I start an external process in Perl?

Tags: perl, process, pid

I want to start a process, get its PID, and write it to a PID file. I then want to check that file, get the PID, and check if the process is running with `kill 0`.

If the process is not running, I want to start it, get its PID, and write it to the PID file. If the process is already running, then I want to ignore it.

How can I start a process so that it keeps running and I can check its status with Perl?

Comment: Have a look at [`fork`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html).

Comment: Sounds a lot like Proc::PID::File (https://metacpan.org/pod/Proc::PID::File)

Comment: `init.d` usually handles that

Comment: may i have more specifics? i tried some things using your information, but i need to know which thing i can start. i tried these things:

Comment: i tried:
perl -e 'use Proc::PID::File;' [not installed]
[user@server init.d]$ syslog
bash: syslog: command not found
[user@server init.d]$ /etc/init.d/syslog
Usage: /etc/init.d/syslog {start|stop|status|restart|condrestart}
[m75926@m5deveet01 init.d]$ sshd
bash: sshd: command not found
[user@server init.d]$ /etc/init.d/sshd
Usage: /etc/init.d/sshd {start|stop|restart|reload|condrestart|status}

perl -e 'my $var1 = exec `sar`;print $var1;' [nothing prints]

when i run "top" i see no processes i started. 
thx in advance for more specific information, please.

Answer (score 1):

It is traditional on UNIX for a process to manage its own PID file if it is understood that other processes will need its PID as a way to interact with it.

But.. If you use fork/exec to start the process, the parent receives the pid of the child process upon successful fork().

If you give us more detail, we can give more precise help.

---------------------  2014-11-04 -----------------

Your web services 'should' be creating their own PID files (Many commercially available server solutions do this already). But you don't say how those services are started, nor what kind of processes they are: apache, iis, node, websphere, etc.

In general, this feels like an `XY` problem. You tell us you want to do `X` but the bogger picture is that you're doing `Y` and there's a better way to to `Y` than just doing `X`.

So please tell us about the environment and the software.

Comment: tasked with a dashboard showing if certain web services are running/if not, then restart them - all using pid files to determine if each is running. so i have a .pl file that chks if -e pid file, if so then is process running? if so->ignore. if file but not process, restart process, create pid file with its number. if file !exist but process running, then get pid and write into new file. if file !exist && process not running, restart process, get #, write into new file. >>so i want to test by creating a process i know i can check if running, and get its #. if this info not enough pls say!

Comment: What I'd do is write a wrapper `withpidfile` that creates its *own* pidfile and records its *own* pid in it, and that, when killed, kills its children, too.

Comment: thx, all! what i get now is that a file gens its own pid. i need to study how to create another process, not my own. ALSO-tell me if i am not giving u credit on this site for helping. not very familiar, and have left w/o giving proper thanks[by voting, giving points, etc/whatever is the best thing, let me know].